# Windows appear without panel

Tags: xubuntu

in the setting, the window manager is not accessible
 when I open files, and close Bouttons for reuduire are absent and the window can not be move but immediately put the top corner of my screen ... Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type as `xfwm4 --replace`

If thats not worked then do as

press ALT+F2 then type as `xfwm4`.